# What are benefits of samvada sookta?

Tags: scripture, vedas, mantras, rig-veda, hymn

Sookta are generally for some particular purpose. What are the benefits of samvada sookta ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last hymn of the Rigveda i.e., **[Mandala 10 suktam 191](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10191.htm)** is called Samana suktam or Aikamatya suktam, the hymn of equality or unity. It is called samana sooktham because the it is prayed for equality and unity of all the devatas while taking their share which in return results in the welfare of the world.

**Devata** : 1 Agni, 2-4 unity (sangyanam).

**Rishi** : Samvana Angirasa.

**Chandas** : Trishtup chhandas.

The English translation of the suktam is following.

> 1 THOU, mighty Agni, gatherest up all that is precious for thy friend.
>   Bring us all treasures as thou art enkindled in libation's place
>
> 2 Assemble, speak together: let your minds be all of one accord,
>   As ancient Gods unanimous sit down to their appointed share.
>
> 3 The place is common, common the assembly, common the mind, so be their thought united.
>    A common purpose do I lay before you, and worship with your general oblation.
>
> 4 One and the same be your resolve, and be your minds of one accord.
>   United be the thoughts of all that all may happily agree.

Below is a YouTube video of the same hymn with alternate English translation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHoFIAb6S6Y